# Ray vectors of a point definition

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Can anyone help me with this, please?

In this context:

"Show the following property of the tangent to an ellipse: the tangent to an ellipse at a point
M coincides with the exterior bisector of the angle of the ray vectors of M."

What are the ray vectors of a point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? I'm pretty sure that's what's meant. [What are the radial vectors in an ellipse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716456/what-are-the-radial-vectors-in-an-ellipse)